# Certifications needed for FinTech companies

Tags: security, pci-compliance, pci-dss, secure-coding

I am trying to do some research on all the types of certifications needed for a FinTech company like PCI-DSS, etc. What all other certification can be used by the company, in terms of IT security as well. To know that this company is having these such and such certifications.
Please let me know.

Comment: It very much depends on exactly what you're doing and how big you are.  The relevant things for handling credit cards are different from the ones for handling checks/ACH.  And if you're doing a quarter million transactions per year it's a very different level of scrutiny compared to if you're doing two million per day.

Comment: @Bobson We are a start up company, let's say that is doing about 2000 - 5000 transactions. We are still very new to the market. But we want to make sure, we are taking all precautions in regards to security since we're dealing in payments. We are in process of PCI compliant. We want to know what other certifications can we have to ensure we are handling everything securely.